# SugarCRM 6 logic hooks

Tags: hook, sugarcrm

I'm developing an logic hook for calls, meetings and tasks, but I can't get it to work!
I have done many logic hooks but the module calls, meetings and tasks seems to ignore the logic_hook.php file!

So, I have created a logic_hooks.php in custom/modules folder with the hook 'before_save' (like the others that I have created until now - I also tried the after_save), but it didn't work so I putted separated logic_hooks.php in custom/modules/tasks because I thought that SugarCRM ignored the logic_hooks.php in custom/modules folder in this modules.
But still can't get it to work! (the content of the function is a die(), so no errors in code - I checked the sugarcrm.log)

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Can you post your code here? I've had my fair share of success with LH's after weeks of wading through manuals and posts. I may be able to help you out here.